# Postgres array query

Tags: sql, postgresql

(The following is a highly simplified description of my problem. The company policy does not allow me to describe the actual scenario in any detail.)

The DB tables involved are:

```
PRODUCTS:
ID   Name
---------
1    Ferrari
2    Lamborghini
3    Volvo


CATEGORIES:
ID    Name
----------
10    Sports cars
20    Safe cars
30    Red cars

PRODUCTS_CATEGORIES
ProductID    CategoryID
-----------------------
1            10
1            30
2            10
3            20

LOCATIONS:
ID      Name
------------
100     Sports car store
200     Safe car store
300     Red car store
400     All cars r us


LOCATIONS_CATEGORIES:
LocationID    CategoryID
------------------------
100           10
200           20
300           30
400           10
400           20
400           30
```

Note that the locations are not directly connected to the products, only the categories. The customer should be able to see a list of locations that can provide all the product categories that the products they want to buy belong to. So, for example:

A customer wants to buy a Ferrari. This would be available from stores in categories 10 *or* 30. This gives us stores 100, 300 and 400 but not 200.

However, if a customer wants to buy a Volvo and a Lamborghini this would be available from stores in categories 10 *and* 20. Which only gives us store 400.

Another customer wants to buy a Ferrari and a Volvo. This they could get from a store in either categories 10 + 20 (sporty and safe) or categories 30 + 20 (red and safe).

What I need is a postgres query that takes a number of products and returns the locations where all of them can be found. I got started with arrays and the <@ operator but got lost quickly. Here follows some example SQL that attempts to get stores where a Ferrari and a Lamborghini can be bought. It does not work correctly since it requires the locations to satisfy *all* the categories that *all* the selected cars belong to. It returns location 400 only but should return locations 400 and 100.

```
SELECT l.* FROM locations l
WHERE 
(SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT(categoryid)) FROM products_categories WHERE productid IN (1,2))
<@
(SELECT array_agg(categoryid) FROM locations_categories WHERE locationid = l.id);
```

I hope my description makes sense.

Comment: Arrays aren't necessary here, you can do all this by multiply joining tables.

Comment: I did some thinking along those lines but couldn't really get it together. Could you possibly help me out with some more details?

Comment: Sure, if you put your sample data into a http://sqlfiddle.com/ I'll give it a go.

Comment: Really appreciate the help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e138d/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the query. You should insert a list of selected cars Ids `pc.ProductId in (1,3)` and in the end you should correct condition to selected cars count so if you select 1 and 3 you should write `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pc.ProductId) = 2`  if you select 3 cars then there have to be 3. This condition in `HAVING` give you condition that ALL cars are in these Locations:

```
SELECT Id FROM Locations l
JOIN Locations_Categories lc on l.Id=lc.LocationId
JOIN Products_Categories pc on lc.CategoryId=pc.CategoryID
where pc.ProductId in (1,3)
GROUP BY l.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pc.ProductId) = 2
```

<kbd>[Sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a17a/5)</kbd>

For example for one car it will be:

```
SELECT Id FROM Locations l
JOIN Locations_Categories lc on l.Id=lc.LocationId
JOIN Products_Categories pc on lc.CategoryId=pc.CategoryID
where pc.ProductId in (1)
GROUP BY l.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pc.ProductId) = 1
```

<kbd>[Only Ferrary demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a17a/3)</kbd>
<kbd>[Volvo and a Lamborghini demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a17a/4)</kbd>

Comment: I only properly understood this after posting mine. This is and equivalent approach to what I wrote, and was posted earlier; all I've done differently is mapped the product *names*, which is trivial, and done the count slightly differently. So this should be accepted in preference to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

(This basically elaborates on @valex's answer, though I didn't realise that until I posted; please accept @valex's not this one).

---

This can be done using only joins and aggregation.

Build a join tree mapping locations to products, as normal. Then join it with the list of desired products (one-column values rows) and filter the join to only matching product names. You now have one row with the location of a product wherever that product can be found.

Now group by location and return locations where the number of products present is equal to the number we're looking for (for ALL). For ANY we omit the `HAVING` filter because any location row returned by the join is what we want.

So:

```
WITH wantedproducts(productname) AS (VALUES('Volvo'), ('Lamborghini'))
SELECT l."ID"
FROM locations l
INNER JOIN locations_categories lc ON (l."ID" = lc."LocationID")
INNER JOIN categories c ON (c."ID" = lc."CategoryID")
INNER JOIN products_categories pc ON (pc."CategoryID" = c."ID")
INNER JOIN products p ON (p."ID" = pc."ProductID")
INNER JOIN wantedproducts wp ON (wp.productname = p."Name")
GROUP BY l."ID"
HAVING count(DISTINCT p."ID") = (SELECT count(*) FROM wantedproducts);
```

is what you want, basically.

For "stores with any of the wanted products" queries, drop the `HAVING` clause.

You an also `ORDER BY` the aggregate if you want to show stores with any match but sort based on number of matches.

You can also add a `string_agg(p."Name")` to the `SELECT` values-list if you want to list products that can be found at that store.

If you want your input to be an array rather than a values-list, just replace the `VALUES (...)` with `SELECT unnest($1)` and pass your array as the parameter `$1`, or write it literally in place of `$1`.

Comment: You should use `COUNT(DISTINCT L.Id)` as soon as one product can be included in different Categories so it can be counted more than one time.

Comment: @valex Good point, but it has to be `p."ID"`; `DISTINCT l."ID"` when grouping by `l."ID"` is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER IN PROGRESS: (I will add answers as I get the required result)

For your first question:

> A customer wants to buy a Ferrari. This would be available from stores
>   in categories 10 or 30. This gives us stores 100, 300 and 400 but not
>   200.

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.id, l.name
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Product_Categories p_c
ON p.id = p_c.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Categories c
ON p_c.CategoryId = c.id
LEFT JOIN Locations_Categories l_c
ON c.id = l_c.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN Locations l
ON l_c.LocationId = l.id
WHERE p.id = 1
```

Second question:

> However, if a customer wants to buy a Volvo and a Lamborghini this
>   would be available from stores in categories 10 and 20. Which only
>   gives us store 400.

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.id, l.name
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Product_Categories p_c
ON p.id = p_c.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Categories c
ON p_c.CategoryId = c.id
LEFT JOIN Locations_Categories l_c
ON c.id = l_c.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN Locations l
ON l_c.LocationId = l.id
WHERE l.id in (select id
               from locations loc
               join locations_categories locat1              
               on loc.id = locat1.LocationId
               join locations_categories locat2
               on loc.id = locat2.LocationId
               where locat1.CategoryId = 10
               AND locat2.categoryId = 20)
```

RESULT FOR SECOND QUESTION USING INTERSECT:
intersect will cross reference all the stores where 1 product can be found each time:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.id, l.name
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Product_Categories p_c
ON p.id = p_c.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Categories c
ON p_c.CategoryId = c.id
LEFT JOIN Locations_Categories l_c
ON c.id = l_c.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN Locations l
ON l_c.LocationId = l.id
WHERE p.id = 2
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT l.id, l.name
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Product_Categories p_c
ON p.id = p_c.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Categories c
ON p_c.CategoryId = c.id
LEFT JOIN Locations_Categories l_c
ON c.id = l_c.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN Locations l
ON l_c.LocationId = l.id
WHERE p.id = 3
```

For every new product you add a new INTERSECT statement and create a new select with the wanted product id 
SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ce97d/15

Comment: I'm starting to think this is not the way you want it, I'm guessing you want 1 query to do everything? though this level of complexity might be slightly over my head

Comment: That is exactly the problem. Ideally I would like to be able to input any number of products to this one query and get the locations where all of the products can be found. But maybe it is not possible. And in that case, perhaps it may be better to just do the filtering in the application layer instead. What do you think?

Comment: So your input will always be a list of products? not categories?

Comment: are you dynamically creating your sql?

Comment: Ideally it should be as static as possible, but dynamic creation is fine also.

Comment: if you can do a select for each product selected and intersect the results it would do what you need

Comment: It's probably not the most performant way of doing things but it's the only way I am able to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to totally avoid arrays here but I think I found a solution with less array functions.

Instead of selecting needed locations, I excluded non valid ones.

```
WITH needed_categories AS (
  SELECT p."ID", array_agg(pc."CategoryID") AS at_least_one_should_match
  FROM Products p
  JOIN Products_Categories pc ON p."ID" = pc."ProductID"
  WHERE p."ID" IN (1, 3)
  GROUP BY p."ID"
),
not_valid_locations AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT lc."LocationID", unnest(nc.at_least_one_should_match)
  FROM Locations_Categories lc
  JOIN needed_categories nc ON NOT ARRAY[lc."CategoryID"] && nc.at_least_one_should_match 
  EXCEPT
  SELECT * FROM Locations_Categories
) 
SELECT * 
FROM Locations
WHERE "ID" NOT IN (
  SELECT "LocationID" FROM not_valid_locations
);
```

Here is the SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e138d/78

This works but I'm still trying to avoid double seq scan of the `Location_Categories`.
The fact that cars can belong to multiple categories is a bit tricky, I solved this using arrays but I'm trying to get rid of these too.

Comment: Avoiding arrays is not really necessary. The db is not huge and this is not a query that will be executed often. So performance is not critical. This is a clever solution. It would not have occured to me to do it backwards like that.

Comment: Well, glad to ear about all this because I'm stuck trying to enhance performance and get rid of arrays :) Is this too complex to be ported to your project ?

Comment: I think it should be ok. I am attempting to port it over now, will let you know how it goes.